# How to average and count in each group and creating a new table

Tags: r

I have a [Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9izMV2W4zC3bUE2cWt3QURueGM/view?usp=sharing), I want to calculate average of KPI, CPM and CPC column and count times column in each score group(1-10).

How to create a new table according results?

A new table looks like:

```
score   avg_KPI avg_CPC avg_CPM count_times
10  
9   
8   
7   
6   
5   
4   
3   
2   
1
```

I try to use For method,but it doesn't work,

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  aa <- subset(dataset1,score== i )
  macroAvgs<-colMeans(aa[,2:4])
  df <- rbind(score="i",KPI=macroAvgs[1],CPC=macroAvgs[2],CPM=macroAvgs[3],times=count(aa[5])
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: **inside your original post** please

Answer (score 1):

assuming your data is in a data.frame called df, do you just want this?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ ,.(lapply(.SD, mean), .N), by = score, .SDcols = c("KPI", "CPM", "CPC")]
```

or do you want this?

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, score) %>%
    summarise(Mean_KPI = mean(KPI),
              Mean_CPC = mean(CPC),
              Mean_CPM = mean(CPM),
              Sum_times = sum(times))
```

Comment: and count the "times" column in each group

Comment: what do you mean with count the times column? add the values in the times column up for each score? and for the future: just copy the head ir parts of your data-frame into the OP and give an example for the desired output